# Mongodb replace field type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I want to change a field type on mongodb for a collection from BsonBinary to ObjectId
I wonder what is the query I should use to convert that field ?

*By mongodb shell*

```
db.company.updateMany({}, {????})
```

[image]

I tried unset then set but still not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a new field which type is ObjectId then fill it by the String field then delete String field for all and rename the new field to the String field name